# Count amount of days within timestamps in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by

Suppose I have a table with the following records: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3af8e/1)

```
| category |               begin |                 end |
|----------|---------------------|---------------------|
|        a | 2017-09-26 08:00:00 | 2017-09-27 10:00:00 |
|        b | 2017-10-02 13:00:00 | 2017-10-03 07:00:00 |
|        a | 2017-10-06 02:00:00 | 2017-10-06 09:00:00 |
|        a | 2017-10-06 11:00:00 | 2017-10-06 14:00:00 |
|        a | 2017-10-06 19:00:00 | 2017-10-08 10:00:00 |
```

I want to be able to count the total amount of distinct days per category (in between begin and end). So: category a contains the periods 26 to 27 September and 6 to 8 October (where 6 October shows up in multiple records), and category b only has the period from 2 to 3 October. I would therefore want to get the following result:

```
| category | days |
|----------|------|
|        a |    5 |
|        b |    2 |
```

from some `GROUP BY category` statement. Is this possible in (My)SQL?

Comment: Should the value for a be 5, not 6?

Comment: I'm sorry, you are correct, I made a mistake when changing the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution involves constructing a "reference table" containing all possible dates for your situation. (For example, you could populate this 20 years into the future, and 20 into the past.) For this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63bac/2), I've just filled in the necessary days. I created `ref_dates` with a single date column `day`, and used the following sql:

```
select category,
count(distinct day)
from times
inner join ref_dates 
    on cast(begin as date) <= day 
    and day <= cast(end as date)
group by category;
```

Answer (score 0):

If they all overlap (as in your example data), you can use:

```
select category, datediff(min(begin), max(end))
from t
group by category;
```

If there are gaps, the problem is much harder.

Comment: No indeed, records do not necessarily overlap, let me fix this in my example data

Answer (score 0):

I would use timestampdiff and make use of a simple sum. This would calculate the sum of differences in minutes for you to then convert as desired.

```
select category,
sum(timestampdiff(minute, begin,end)) as 'diff'
from times
group by category
```

Comment: This is however not exactly as I want it, I want to count the number of distinct dates. So imagine I have two records `2017-08-10 23:00` - `2017-08-10 23:01` and `2017-08-12 11:00 - 2017-08-12 11:01`, I want these to count as two days, just as would the two records `2017-08-10 01:00 - 2017-08-10 23:00` and `2017-08-12 02:00 - 2017-08-12 22:00`

Comment: In that case shouldn't the result of category a actually be 5? Being 26/9, 27/9, 6/10, 7/10 and 8/10??